# RELAX NG C++ Code Generator?

Tags: c++, relaxng

Are there any open source [RELAX NG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELAX_NG) C++ code generator?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused -- do you want something that takes a RELAX NG specification and generates C++ code recognising an XML document conforming to that specification, or do you want a library to create RELAX NG documents?

Comment: takes a RELAX NG specification and generates C++ code recognising an XML document conforming to that specification

Answer (score 1):

I know of none for RELAX NG.  However, if you can bring yourself to generate or convert your schema files as XML Schema, then it would be worthwhile to take a look at the C++ code generators from CodeSynthesis.  They are GPLv2 open source, with proprietary licenses also available.

http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/